# Is it possible to play with 2 players, instead of 4?

Tags: payday-the-heist

A friend and I are considering buying Payday: The Heist for $2 during the Steam Winter Sale. However, if we get it, most likely only my friend and I will be playing matches together.

I've heard the AI in the game isn't that good, and I prefer playing without AI in multi-player games such as Payday. *Is it possible to play a Payday game with 2 players, and remove the other 2 bots?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn off the AI companions with a setting called "Play with team AI" in the game, so **yes**, it is possible to play with just 2 players and no bots.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible, and in my opinion sometimes even preferable. For example, trying stealth on certain missions can be easier if you have two good/careful players, rather than two good players, and two players who run in and trip the alarm.

As, 3ventic said you can disable the AI players if you wish. Typically it is not necessary, since during stealth they'll stand in a safe place (never raising the alarm) and during the cop waves, they can be helpful at holding off cops or reviving you as you take care of other actions.